# Why does my context menu item open the file and the text editor in the editor?

Tags: windows-7

I have created a context menu item to open files with PSPad editor:

In `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT/*/shell`, I have a key called "Open with PSPad", and under that a key called "command". The command values is

`PSPad.exe "%1"`

because PSPad needs its arguments in quotes if they contain spaces.

I can right click a file and I see "Open with PSPad". I select that, and PSPad opens the file. But it also opens the PSPad.exe as a binary file. Have I created the registry key wrong somehow?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just tried this myself, and yeah that's pretty weird. Especially since it only seems to open `PSPad.exe` within PSPad if you've already got it open.

If you use the Windows Installer version of the PSPad setup (vs. Portable) one of the options of Setup is to add a "Edit in PSPad" shortcut to Explorer's context menu. I tried that, and it works as expected... So there's that option at least.

Doesn't explain what you're seeing though...

So, I then recreated the same "Open With PSPad" command again (as in question), only this time I specified the absolute path to PSPad.exe (e.g.: "C:\Program Files (x86)\PSPad editor\PSPad.exe" "%1") and it worked as expected (opening a second file via the context shortcut no longer opens the unwanted `PSPad.exe` in PSPad).

Comment: That is some really weird behavior.